Feature Importance with ColumnTransform and OneHotEncoder in RandomForestClassifier
Apologies for bothering you, but I haven't been able to find a definitive answer after searching the site.
I'm building a RandomForestClassifier on some clinical data where the target variable (outcome) is binary (0 or 1). I'm using Python and scikit-learn to implement this.
The dataset consists of both categorical and numeric variables, and I'm working with a pipeline for preprocessing.
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("imputer", IterativeImputer(max_iter=20, random_state=42)),
    ("scaler", StandardScaler())
])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")),
    ("onehot", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("num", numeric_transformer, numeric_columns),
        ("cat", categorical_transformer, categorical_columns)
    ]
)

model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("preprocessor", preprocessor),
    ("model", model)
])

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=5, scoring="balanced_accuracy", verbose=4, n_jobs = -1)


After obtaining a model called final_model, when I try to extract the feature importances using final_model.feature_importances_, I get an array of 116 values, which corresponds to the number of variables in my dataset.
Question: Since I used OneHotEncoder for the categorical variables, shouldn’t I expect more than 116 values in the array? I believe the answer lies in how ColumnTransformer handles the transformations, but I’m a bit confused at this point.
Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

If you could provide a [mre], it would reduce guesswork on our part. What is len(preprocessor.get_feature_names_out())? How many numeric and how many categorical features?

You should see the same number of columns as your preprocessed features yes. Have you checked numeric_columns and categorical_columns? (Might well be that the processing step is not increasing dimensionality as you expect)

thanks for answering so far!
I have an update: ultimately, the fault was mine. I overlooked a section of the code that I hadn’t shared.
Specifically, when building the final_model with the best parameters selected via GridSearchCV, I failed to include the preprocessing step in the pipeline. As a result, the final model was working with categorical variables that hadn’t been transformed by the OneHotEncoder.
Sorry for not sharing the whole code, the idea of the question was more "theoretical", as I believed that there was something that I was not understanding correctly in the ColumnTransformer function.
Thank you so much, I think I can close this thread.
Bests!
